# geocode google api stuck when convert address to lat long

Tags: java, android, google-api, geocode

When I hit Geocode Google API with Ukrain address it will return `null` for some addresses at client (in Ukrain) but when I test it in India (at my side) it works perfect.

Code:

```
private LatLng getLocationFromAddress(final String place){
    LatLng loc = null;
    Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity() );

    try {
        final List<Address> list = gCoder.getFromLocationName(place, 1);

        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
            loc = new LatLng(list.get(0).getLatitude(), list.get(0).getLongitude());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return loc;
}
```

Comment: show me code, without code we can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Show the code.
Also check if the address is not null from api